# Maven build fails with Spring-cloud-contract-verifier

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I have an issue with building `spring-cloud-contract-verifier` with below pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker-maven-plugin.version>1.2.0</docker-maven-plugin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <geometry.version>2.11</geometry.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--############################################# SPRING ####################################################-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--######################################### SPRING-CLOUD ##################################################-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--############################################## MYSQL ####################################################-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--############################################### GEO #####################################################-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jillesvangurp</groupId>
            <artifactId>geogeometry</artifactId>
            <version>${geometry.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--############################################ MOCKITO ####################################################-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--##################################### END-OF-DEPENDENCIES ###############################################-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <baseClassForTests>
                        com.foo.pricing.contract.BaseClass
                    </baseClassForTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I attempt to `clean install` the project in order to have my test classes be generated by `spring-cloud-contract`.
 `BaseClass`  is as below:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = PricingServiceApplication.class)
    @DirtiesContext
    public class BaseClass {

    @Autowired
    private RateChartController rateChartController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(rateChartController);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);
    }
}
```

The exception I stumble upon comes as follow:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ PricingService ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE:generateStubs (default-generateStubs) @ PricingService ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.079 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-13T16:09:17+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/483M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE:generateStubs (default-generateStubs) on project PricingService: Stubs could not be found: [/home/akarimin/project/foo/pricing-service/pricing/target/stubs] .
[ERROR] Please make sure that spring-cloud-contract:convert was invoked
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I appreciate if you could help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days struggling to find the solution, I came to the conclusion that my Spring Boot version (1.5.10) is not compatible with Spring Cloud Contract Verifier (2.1.1), although I have not found any compatibility matrix on the web and it is just based on my experiment in this case. By migrating to Spring Boot 2.1.x the issue was resolved and it is working like a charm. Many thanks to  Josh Long & Marcin Grzejszczak for the presentation in conference about Spring Contract.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDydAqL4mYE

Comment: Check the main page of Spring Cloud for compatibility matrix - https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud . We also blog about new releases where we mention the boot compatibility - https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/23/spring-cloud-greenwich-release-is-now-available

Comment: Sure I will, appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks that you have no contracts under the default path (src/test/resources/contracts) which results in not copying then to target which results in the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually have my contract under this path. The issue was resolved, so I explain my problem and the way it was solved it.

Answer (score 1):

To apply a temporary solution to the problem, just create a folder contracts under (`src/test/resources`). It should be (`src/test/resources/contracts`) after you have created it.
But you should implement contracts verifiers to satisfy your endpoints accordingly. I hope that helps.